# converge of $\sum_{n≥ 1}\frac{1}{n}\left(e-(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to determine whether the series converges or diverges, so consider that

$\frac{1}{n}\left(e-(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\right)=\frac{\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n}{n}=\frac{e-\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n}{n}+\frac{e}{n}$

I tried to use the comparison criterion to try to narrow that last expression, however I did not find a satisfactory result, any help? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to deduce bounds on $e-\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^n$... It is for instance true that
$$
0< e-\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^n < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},
$$

so, your series is bounded by $\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$, which is a convergent series, thus proving the convergence.

---

Edit: Another possibility is to prove that
$$ (1+\frac{1}{n})^n < e < (1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+1}$$

This way you can show that
$$
e-(1+\frac 1n)^n< (1+\frac 1n)^{n+1}-(1+\frac 1n)^n < \frac{(1+1/n)^n}{n}<\frac{e}{n}.
$$

Comment: You are right, but do you know how I can arrive at such inequality? I am not quite sure.

Comment: You mean "guessing" the proper equality or proving that it holds?

Comment: basically prove that $$ e-\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^n < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}, $$, I don't see how to conclude this equality, could you help me with it please?

Comment: Mathematical induction should do the trick. Along the way it may be useful to remember that $(1+1/n)^n$ is increasing.

Answer (score 1):

More generally,
using
(as $x \to 0$)
$\ln(1+x)
=x-\dfrac{x^2}{2}+O(x^3)
$
and
$e^x
=1+x+O(x^2)
$,

$\begin{array}\\
(1+\frac1{n})^{n+c}
&=e^{\ln(1+\frac1{n})(n+c)}\\
&=e^{(\frac1{n}-\frac1{2n^2}+O(\frac1{n^3}))(n+c)}\\
&=e^{1+\frac{c}{n}-\frac1{2n}-\frac{c}{2n^2}+O(\frac1{n^2})}\\
&=e^{1+\frac{c-\frac12}{n}+O(\frac1{n^2})}\\
&=e\cdot e^{\frac{c-\frac12}{n}+O(\frac1{n^2})}\\
&=e(1+\frac{c-\frac12}{n}+O(\frac1{n^2}))\\
&=e+e\frac{c-\frac12}{n}+O(\frac1{n^2})\\
\end{array}
$

so

$e-(1+\frac1{n})^{n+c}
=-e\frac{c-\frac12}{n}+O(\frac1{n^2})
$

so
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (e-(1+\frac1{n})^{n+c})
$
diverges for
$c \ne \frac12$
and converges for
$c=\frac12$.

Comment: the question was about the convergence of $\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac 1n (e-(1+1/n)^n)$...